# How do you see which commit deleted a file from the repo?

Tags: git

Since it is no longer in the repository, I can't do

```
git log <filename>
```

I can run

```
git log  --diff-filter='D|R' <directory_that_contained_it>
```

but that is too much information and grepping it does not seem to list the file I'm looking for.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
git log -1 --stat -- <path/to/file>
```

I put the `--stat` in there so that you can verify that the file was deleted.

Comment: Interesting. That was the first thing I tried (without the --stat) and it did not work. I've now tried with another repo and it works there. However, it still does not for the original repo. It gives back nothing as if the file had never existed. If I go back to the commit that deleted the file it works but not from the current HEAD.

Comment: It doesn't give anything.

Comment: @BalintErdi I am not sure this will work in situations where the hash id that deleted the file came before the last hash id to touch the file, as is possible when doing a merge between two branches. -- So, this may explain why it doesn't work consistently for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
git log -- <filename>
```

will show you the changes to that path, even if that file isn't present any more.

You can use the `rev-list -n 1` to limit it to the first result returned, which will be the one where it disappeared

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <filename>
```

That revision is when it disappears, so you can find the parent if you want to restore it with ^ on that revision number

Comment: The same caveat that John Zabroski mentions in the other answer seems to apply here. In fact the latter command only returns the commit where the file was added, even after removing -n 1.

Comment: Without using the `--full-history` flag, the `git log` output may miss the critical commit